# Xamarin Firebase Auth with claims

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I have a Xamarin Forms project that we are using Firebase Authentication, Storage and Realtime Database. We are storing credentials for the users (for internal api access) in custom claims. Currently, we are using FirebaseAuthentication.net but it doesn't return any claims beyond DisplayName, email, phone, etc.

How do others retrieve custom claims on Xamarin Forms apps (iOS and Android).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Firebase.Xamarin` instead. This package is easy to get the DisplayName, email, etc.

```
var authProvider = new Firebase.Xamarin.Auth.FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(""));
        var auth = await authProvider.SignInWithOAuthAsync(authType, accessToken);
        var uName = auth.User.DisplayName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I needed to get the custom claims and with this library 6 years old, not sure it will get it done. I like that it has database in it too - but not sure its worth the effort. I see 40 open bugs and they are all old (2016-2018 with only two in 2019. What I did find was Plugin.FirebaseAuth which does allow me to query for the custom claims configured for the user. But - it looks like it is breaking the database access I already had.